# C# WP8 dynamically increase control size according to text

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I am trying to achieve below. I have created a control as you can see below where I am showing restricted test in textblock initially but as user click on readmore button I have to expand control size according to text inside the text block. Refer below image.

[image]

How to achieve this any help? This control will be added in another user control which is collection of this control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are restricting the text by some means and then adding more text, you can accomplish this with really any panel control. Do not give the panel (or it's parent) a width or height property so that it can grow. Here is an example using a Grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Event"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventSummary}" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding SummaryVis}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventDescription}" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding DescriptionVis}" />
    <HyperlinkButton HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="read more" Command="{Binding ReadMoreCommand}" />
    <!-- Buttons -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
</Grid>
```

In the ReadMoreCommand you would change the visibility of the two textblocks

```
private void ReadMore(object val)
{
    DescriptionVis = Visibility.Visible;
    SummaryVis = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: will it automatically increase the size of user control. I doubt that, because when I am adding this user control in another control I am setting usercontrol height and width. How that is going to get updated? Somehow I need a mechanism to compute new height of user control?

Comment: As I mention, you should not be setting height within your application. You should allow the heights to be determined on the fly